# Stripe Elements custom font - Cloud Typography

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, stripe-payments, stripe.js

Trying to obtain my custom font from cloud typography to the stripe elements but a CORS error occurs. I'm sure this is not cloud typography related error as the font loads on the website. When I create the elements instance, I'm correctly targeting the `fontFamily` as well.

Stripe elements error:

```
 stripeElements = stripe.elements({
   fonts: [
     {
       cssSrc: "https://cloud.typography.com/NUMBER/NUMBER/css/fonts.css"
     }
   ]
 })
```

CORS error:
[image]

Any ideas on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Did you specify `localhost:3000` as a valid domain on cloud.typography.com?  I'm guessing, but it looks like they're just throwing a fit serving it to a domain they aren't aware of here. 
 https://dashboard.typography.com/user-guide/managing-domains

Comment: Not sure, it is a client domain. But the font works on the website, loading as localhost. The only problem is with Stripe.